# Linux environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, rhel

Is there any command to get only the exported variables in RHEL.

For ex: If I exporting multiple variable line by line like below,

```
export AIR_HOME=value1
export PATH=value2
```

Is there any command to see only the exported variables. I tried `printenv` and `env` and it didn't worked for me it is printing the entire environment variables. Also `echo $AIR_HOME` will not work in my case since the exported variable name will change in different situation.

Comment: All the environment variables reported by `env` are exported.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make any sense. The `printenv` and `env` commands do exactly what you asked for: they print only the exported vars. There is no way to distinguish the vars you added to the environment via the `export` builtin from those already in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

> echo "$VARIABLENAME"

For example for the environment variable $AIR_HOME, use:

> echo "$AIR_HOME"

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, echo $AIR_HOME will not work in my case since the exported variable name will change in different situation.

Comment: Its echo "$AIR_HOME" .. Try it

Comment: If I know the variable which I exported, I can print like this. But the question is If I not know the variable name how to print? for ex: if I am exporting number of variables using env file how to print the variables which are exported.

Comment: There is no distinction between variables that you exported or that somebody (or something) else exported. Or: Are you maybe looking for `export` (without arguments)?